# Failing to build/test (bazel) Syntaxnet (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I am trying to run the basic tutorial following the instruction at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet

I am getting the following error when I do `bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...`

Following is the error snippet:

> //syntaxnet:arc_standard_transitions_test PASSED in 0.0s
>   //syntaxnet:parser_features_test PASSED in 0.0s
>   //syntaxnet:sentence_features_test PASSED in 0.0s
>   //syntaxnet:shared_store_test PASSED in 0.2s
>   //syntaxnet:tagger_transitions_test PASSED in 0.0s
>   //util/utf8:unicodetext_unittest PASSED in 0.0s
>   //syntaxnet:beam_reader_ops_test FAILED in 0.1s
>   //syntaxnet:graph_builder_test FAILED in 0.1s
>   //syntaxnet:lexicon_builder_test FAILED in 0.1s
>   //syntaxnet:parser_trainer_test FAILED in 0.1s
>   //syntaxnet:reader_ops_test FAILED in 0.1s
>   //syntaxnet:text_formats_test FAILED in 0.1s
>   
>   Executed 12 out of 12 tests: 6 tests pass and 6 fail locally.
>   There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.

Is anybody familiar with this kind of error?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: something is not right with your tensorflow setup. did you checkout straight or just updated from an older repository? They do pass on my linux machine. Are you on Macosx?

Comment: The log files for those tests (which will tell you why those tests failed) can be found in the output above the stuff you pasted.  Please take a look at those and paste the actual reasons for the failed tests in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem,until I found that it was a memory related problem.I build it on Ubuntu 14.04 with `--local_resources 2048,.5,1.0` flag. Follow these steps:

**1** *get coorect version of bazel* `wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.2b/bazel-0.2.2b-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`

**2** `chmod +x bazel-0.2.2b-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`

**3** `./bazel-0.2.2b-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user`

**4** `git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git`

**5** `cd /models/syntaxnet/tensorflow`

**6** `./configure`

**7** `cd ..`

**8** `bazel test --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0 --genrule_strategy=standalone syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...`

Hope this will help others!

Comment: Haven't tried this but I agree it's probably a resource problem. I added `--jobs 4`

Comment: Mihai, can you specify what those additional flags stand for. I get the following error when I write those flags `The 'test' command is only supported from within a workspace.`

Comment: Yes you have to be in `models/syntaxnet` root folder from the git repo to run bazel. After installing correct version of bazel follow these steps:1 `git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git` 2 `cd /models/syntaxnet/tensorflow `  3 `./configure`  4 `bazel test --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0 --genrule_strategy=standalone syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...` It has worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing your Virtual RAM. I had to make it 8GBs just to get it to work.

This link might help for that.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, test it by using this command instead:

```
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names \
syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```